# Laravel passport: createToken with time life

Tags: laravel, time, token

Even if I have Passport::tokensExpireIn($time) in a Service provider, when I create a user token with:

```
$user->createToken('Token');
```

the life time is about 1 year I think? How I can change the life time without using   DB::table ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Laravel docs, you pass `tokenExpiresIn` on the `AuthServiceProvider` boot function

Are you sure that your AuthServiceProvider is setup correctly as detailed in the docs?

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#configuration

----- EDIT

Personal access tokens are always long lived according to the docs.

> Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not modified when using the tokensExpireIn or refreshTokensExpireIn methods.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#personal-access-tokens

It looks like there is a ServiceProvider that will solve your problem in this Github Issue

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/162

Comment: I made a separate ServiceProvider for Passport. When I call the /oauth/token the token life time is good, only in createToken for user model doesn't work.

Comment: I found a Github Issue that may have a solution for you